# Screen freezes when popBackStack() is called

Tags: android, fragment, freeze, fragment-backstack

I have two fragments A & B.

I have switched to B from A using following code :

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim,R.animator.popenter, R.animator.popexit);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, new B())
            .addToBackStack("tag").commit();
```

B contains SQLite operations(SugarORM). 

 While switching from A to B, the screen freezes, even if I am using `AsyncTask` & `IntentService` for db operations.

Also, when I press back button [`getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`], the screen freezes for couple of seconds, before it switches back to A from B.

The `popBackStack` animation is too not visible.

I tried showing indeterminate progress bar & animation-list in imageview, but they freeze too & it looks as if they are static images.

Comment: check if your FRAGMENT A has any ui blocking calls in onCreateView/onViewCreated.

Comment: post your AsyncTask. and you can see animation by increasing delay .

Comment: put logs in all your methods in both fragments and you can find out by checking logs during which two process(between which 2 logs) so long time is taken and you can rectify the reason.(specially in onResume or in onPause)If possible paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article on profiling your main thread: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

This will show you what's hogging the main thread, which is probably the reason for the freeze.

Also, follow @NishantPardamwar's advice for checking the fragment's lifecycle methods, which run on the main thread and are likely culprits.